# jquery datatable is slow if i use select box in each row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery data table and each row is having two select boxes in two cells.
One select box is having around 400 option values and another select box is having around 30 options values.
I am rendering around 15 rows at a time.

In this case,rendering is very slow and it hangs my browser for some seconds.

Any solution for fast performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could delay filling the select boxes until the user clicks on them, that way you keep your DOM clean until you need the options. If the options are the same across all rows considder creating only one select box and positioning it over the row the user hovers with his mouse.